# How does one get Python to find `libusb`? `pyusb` needs it for a backend

Tags: python, usb, python-module, libusb, osx-yosemite

I am trying to use Python 2.7 with PyUSB to talk to a National Instruments DAQ board. I am using a MacBook Pro and running Yosemite 10.10.4. I have been able to install Python and the PyUSB package without any obvious problems, but when I try to use PyUSB, it cannot find a backend library:

```
>>> import usb.core
>>> usb.core.find()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 1, in <module>
    usb.core.find()
  File        "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 1199, in find
    raise ValueError('No backend available')
ValueError: No backend available
```

I have attempted to install `libusb-1.0` multiple different ways but Python cannot seem to find any module named `libusb`. I tried:

1. Downloading the tarball from SourceForge
2. Installing brew and using "brew install libusb-compat" and "brew link libusb-compat"
3. using sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib") to help Python find `libusb`

and this is where I get desperate:

4. Using pip to "pip install libusb" (does pip even work with libraries?)
5. Copying the contents of /usr/local/lib where the `libusb-1.0.dylib` and other `libusb` files are located to various locations where I thought Python might be looking for it.

Nevertheless, when I call `help("Modules")` in either IDLE or iPython, nothing resembling `libusb` shows up and calls to usb.core.find() continue to complain about a missing Backend.

How does one get Python to find `libusb`? Is the fact that it doesn't show up in `help("Modules")` even related to usb.core.find() complaining about a lack of a Backend?

I've dropped a good day on this so far and read a good 20 Q&As with no avail. Any advice would be quite welcome at this point. Also, this is my first ever question for stackoverflow, so please ask me to clarify if I've omitted critically enabling information or structured my question poorly. Thanks.

Comment: Another similar question seems to have been resolved via:

    _"Apparently, both rfcat and ipython binaries pointed to the wrong binaries of python - not /opt/local/bin/python. Changed that in vim, and it all runs fine."_

I don't know how to try this because I'm not sure what file to edit to make iPython or IDLE point to a different binary. Nor do I know which binary it could and should be pointing to, but that I can resolve by trial-and-error.

Comment: Did you try `brew install libusb`?  The `libusb-compat` library is just a library that allows applications written for libusb 0.1 to work with libusb 1.0.  I would think that PyUSB would already work with libusb 1.0 these days, so it wouldn't need some compatibility layer like that.  You might also need to use a version of python installed from brew instead of using whatever version you are using now; I'm not sure.

Comment: YES! All my symbolic links in /usr/local/bin were pointing to the wrong instance of python (i.e. the one that came from the tarball). I removed that python and removed the brew python, cleaned everything up, and re-installed the brew python. Everything works flawlessly now! I hadn't realized that brew would create a new version of Python, rather than just finding the one that was already there.

Thanks so much!

Comment: David Grayson, one last Q. Now that you've convinced me that stackoverflow is awesome, how can I mark your comment as useful? Or is that not possible because it was just a comment and not an "answer" attempt?

Comment: Great!  I have copied my comment to an answer below so you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark, and also upvote it.  You can also maybe upvote my comment (hover on it and click the up triangle), but that doesn't give me any reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `brew install libusb`? The `libusb-compat` library is just a library that allows applications written for libusb 0.1 to work with libusb 1.0. I would think that PyUSB would already work with libusb 1.0 these days, so it wouldn't need some compatibility layer like that. You might also need to use a version of python installed from brew instead of using whatever version you are using now; I'm not sure.

Comment: YES! All my symbolic links in /usr/local/bin were pointing to the wrong instance of python (i.e. the one that came from the tarball). I removed that python and removed the brew python, cleaned everything up, and re-installed the brew python. Everything works flawlessly now! I hadn't realized that brew would create a new version of Python, rather than just finding the one that was already there. Thanks so much!